# AWS is complaining about a parameter being the wrong type, when it really is not

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am new at AWS. Like 3 days new. I found in one of the Amazon's tutorials the code for a lambda function that would interact with a DynamoDB table. The sample is only providing the test JSON for a GET request, which would result in a list of items in the database, but the code itself supports PUT, POST and DELETE, for a full CRUD with the table.

So, I created a DynamoDB table named "Users" with a partition key ***CompanyId*** which is a string, and a sort key ***Email*** which is also a string.
[image: The Users table]

I then created a lambda function and added the code from the tutorial:

```
console.log('Loading function');

const doc = require('dynamodb-doc');

const dynamo = new doc.DynamoDB();

/**
 * Demonstrates a simple HTTP endpoint using API Gateway. You have full
 * access to the request and response payload, including headers and
 * status code.
 *
 * To scan a DynamoDB table, make a GET request with the TableName as a
 * query string parameter. To put, update, or delete an item, make a POST,
 * PUT, or DELETE request respectively, passing in the payload to the
 * DynamoDB API as a JSON body.
 */
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));

    const done = (err, res) => callback(null, {
        statusCode: err ? '400' : '200',
        body: err ? err.message : JSON.stringify(res),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
    });

    switch (event.httpMethod) {
        case 'DELETE':
            dynamo.deleteItem(JSON.parse(event.body), done);
            break;
        case 'GET':
            dynamo.scan({ TableName: event.queryStringParameters.TableName }, done);
            break;
        case 'POST':
            console.log(event.body);
            dynamo.putItem(JSON.parse(event.body), done);
            break;
        case 'PUT':
            dynamo.updateItem(JSON.parse(event.body), done);
            break;
        default:
            done(new Error(`Unsupported method "${event.httpMethod}"`));
    }
};
```

After testing the GET code (and getting a 0-length list of items, since my table is empty), I decided to create a test that would add one item to the database. I created a test event called PostTest and with the following test content:

```
{
  "httpMethod": "POST",
  "body": "{\"Item\": {\"CompanyId\": {\"S\": \"test-company-id\"},\"FirstName\": {\"S\": \"John\"}, \"LastName\": {\"S\": \"Doe\"}, \"Email\": {\"S\": \"john.doe@gmail.com\"}, \"Password\": {\"S\": \"password\"}}, \"TableName\": \"Users\"}"
}
```

I want to point out the fact that the ***CompanyId*** is set to be a "S", or in other words, set to be of type string.

When I ran the test, I got the following response:

```
{
  "statusCode": "400",
  "body": "One or more parameter values were invalid: Type mismatch for key CompanyId expected: S actual: M",
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }
}
```

and the content of the log was:

```
START RequestId: 294a7414-cde5-11e8-a7bd-bd58483e1612 Version: $LATEST
2018-10-12T06:07:56.232Z    294a7414-cde5-11e8-a7bd-bd58483e1612    Received event: {
  "httpMethod": "POST",
  "body": "{\"Item\": {\"CompanyId\": {\"S\": \"test-company-id\"},\"FirstName\": {\"S\": \"John\"}, \"LastName\": {\"S\": \"Doe\"}, \"Email\": {\"S\": \"john.doe@gmail.com\"}, \"Password\": {\"S\": \"password\"}}, \"TableName\": \"Users\"}"
}
2018-10-12T06:07:56.232Z    294a7414-cde5-11e8-a7bd-bd58483e1612    {"Item": {"CompanyId": {"S": "test-company-id"},"FirstName": {"S": "John"}, "LastName": {"S": "Doe"}, "Email": {"S": "john.doe@gmail.com"}, "Password": {"S": "password"}}, "TableName": "Users"}
END RequestId: 294a7414-cde5-11e8-a7bd-bd58483e1612
REPORT RequestId: 294a7414-cde5-11e8-a7bd-bd58483e1612  Duration: 173.04 ms Billed Duration: 200 ms     Memory Size: 512 MB Max Memory Used: 30 MB
```

I am baffled by the error in the response:

```
Type mismatch for key CompanyId expected: S actual: M
```

If you look in the log, in the body of the request ***CompanyId*** is set to "S". Where does "M" come from? What did I do wrong?

Needless to say that no items have been added to my table.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what is behind `dynamodb-doc`, but I had similar issue with `aws-sdk`.

Given `const AWS = require('aws-sdk')` you may have two connectors. Example:

- `const DDB = new AWS.DynamoDB();`
- `const DC = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();`

When using the `DDB` connection, you have to format the items the way you do, using the types.

When using the DocumentClient (`DC`) the types are inferred, thus you do not have to explicitly provide the types. Try something like this:

```
{
  "httpMethod": "POST",
  "body": "{\"Item\": {\"CompanyId\": \"test-company-id\",\"FirstName\": \"John\", \"LastName\": \"Doe\", \"Email\": \"john.doe@gmail.com\", \"Password\":  \"password\"}, \"TableName\": \"Users\"}"
}
```

Using the `DC`, the CompanyId is correctly inferred as a Map: `{\"S\": \"test-company-id\"}`. Garbage in, garbage out. :)

Comment: Costin, thank you. Both suggestions worked. I read on the DocumentClient, and I like it. I know I may run into its limitations at some point, but I think that for now it will cover what I need.

Comment: You are welcome, Tibi. I use DocumentClient since a while and I am very happy with it. I've only had some issues when working with StringSets, there were some differences between testing with `dynamodb-local` and AWS. Come back with a question when needed... meanwhile use Document Client, it's much simpler ;)